# Unable to unbind arrow keys from python tkinter ttk.Treeview widget

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, ttk

I am writing a program that uses a ttk.Treeview widget and also has a tk.scale slider widget.
I want to bind the left and right arrow key events to the slider widget, which works, but I find that the Treeview widget is automatically bound to those keys as well.

When I try to move my slider with the arrows, I find I am also navigating in the treeview object.

I have tried unbinding the keys from both my surrounding Tk class as well as from the treeview widget itself with no change (I've even run the unbind in the treeview open_node callback with no change).

This may be a feature of Tcl/Tk that cannot be affected from within Python, but I want to see if a fix is possible.

I'm using Python 3.10

In addition to trying unbinding, I've also created a minimal-ish program that illustrates the problem.  My interest is in breaking the binding of the arrow keys to treeview - not in the resulting exception that appears because this example doesn't completely populate the tree.

The key binding is the issue!

I'd appreciate any insight.

```
""" Minimal example to illustrate hidden binding of arrow keys to ttk.Treeview
    To see problem: run program, double click to expand 'top_node' 
      then click on 'leaf_node' and hit right arrow key
    Program generates a Tcl Exception: cannot delete root item as a result of   
      trying to open a leaf-node.
    But the issue is that I can find no way to unbind the arrow keys to use them
      for another purpose.
"""
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MinimalTree(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, height=25, takefocus=False)
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.nodes = dict()
        self.insert_node('', 'top_node', 'top_node')
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.open_node)
        self.unbind_now()

    def insert_node(self, parent, text, path):
        node = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=text, open=False)
        self.nodes[node] = path
        if path == 'top_node':
            self.tree.insert(node, 'end')
        self.unbind_now()

    def open_node(self, event):
        print(f'open_node {event}')
        node = self.tree.focus()
        abspath = self.nodes.pop(node, None)
        if abspath:
            self.tree.delete(self.tree.get_children(node))
            self.insert_node(node, 'leaf_node', 'top_node/leaf_node')
        self.unbind_now()

    def unbind_now(self):  # doesn't help: '<Right>' still calls open_node
        self.tree.unbind('<Left>')
        self.tree.unbind('<Right>')
        self.unbind('<Left>')
        self.unbind('<Right>')


app = MinimalTree()
app.mainloop()
```

Below is an update to the code using the suggestion in acw1668's comment and also adding a slider.

With this code, neither the treeview nor the scale slider receive the left and right keys once the tree is opened (although the slider does receive any left or right arrows pressed before the treeview tree is opened for the first time).

However, if I comment out the two bind statements with 'break', then both the slider and treeview receive the same key strokes.

This appears to be in violation of only one widget receiving a key event.

If this is not solvable, then I see two fallbacks - one is to use different keys for the slider (not optimal) and the other is to put the treeview in its own top-level window which will force the assignment of keyboard focus (but klunky for the user).

Code with slider:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MinimalTree(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, height=25, takefocus=False)
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.nodes = dict()
        self.insert_node('', 'top_node', 'top_node')
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.open_node)

        # fix from acw1668's comment on Stackoverflow
        # which does block the left and right arrow event on the tree:
        self.tree.bind('<Left>', lambda e: 'break')
        self.tree.bind('<Right>', lambda e: 'break')

        # adding a Scale widget with arrow key focus
        # but I find the 'break' bindings above keep these new bindings from working
        # If I remove the two 'break' bindings, then both widget get the arrow keys,
        # but if I included the breaks, neither widget gets the keys
        # how to allow the Scale to bind to the arrows but break the binding of the treeview?
        self.scale = tk.Scale(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, width=20, command=self.scroll, showvalue=0)
        self.scale.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.bind('<Left>', lambda e: self.scale.set(self.scale.get() - 1))
        self.bind('<Right>', lambda e: self.scale.set(self.scale.get() + 1))

    def scroll(self, event):
        print(f'scale scrolled to {self.scale.get()}')
        # self.bind_to_scale()

    def insert_node(self, parent, text, path):
        node = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=text, open=False)
        self.nodes[node] = path
        if path == 'top_node':
            self.tree.insert(node, 'end')

    def open_node(self, event):
        node = self.tree.focus()
        abspath = self.nodes.pop(node, None)
        if abspath:
            self.tree.delete(self.tree.get_children(node))
            for i in range(5):
                name = f'leaf node {i}'
                self.insert_node(node, 'name', f'top_node/{name}')

app = MinimalTree()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can disable the default handling of the left or right arrow key in the treeview by using `self.tree.bind("<Left>", lambda e: "break")` and `self.tree.bind("<Right>", lambda e: "break")`.

Comment: _"When I try to move my slider with the arrows..."_ - The code you posted doesn't have a slider.

Comment: @Brian - please see updated code above - I initially didn't know how to update my post and add the new code.

Answer (score 0):

For the default bindings to not fire, you need to bind the events to a function that returns the string `"break"`. If you do that, all further processing of the event is halted.

Your call to `unbind` doesn't work because the default bindings are on the widget's internal class rather than the widget itself or on the root window. The widget itself doesn't have bindings for `<Left>` and `<Right>` so there's nothing for `unbind` to remove.

Comment: Including the bindings to 'break' does indeed stop the treeview from receiving the arrow keys.  However, when I add a scale slider to the example and bind it to the same keys then neither receives the key events. 
If I remove the 'break' statements, both the treeview and the scale get the event.
With the break, neither.
The break appears to be persisting past a subsequent binding of the key to the slider.  Is there any way to use the key for a different widget's event after the break for the treeview?

Comment: @DonH: that's a complicated question that I can't answer in the comments. However, I think you're misinterpreting what you're seeing. Events are only given to a single widget. For the slider to accept keyboard input, the slider needs to have the keyboard focus.

Comment: I believe I've solved the problem - I had assumed that clicking on the slider would set keyboard focus on the slider, but that is not default behavior.

Simply tabbing to the slider moves focus, then the arrow keys (if bound to the slider) will move it.

I also added self.scale.focus_set() to the command callback for the slider to ensure it gets focus once clicked.